# NSDocumentTitlebarPopoverViewController moving untitled NSDocument file on first click

Tags: macos, nsdocument

I've got an odd situation with my NSDocument-based macOS app running on Sierra (10.12.5):

- Launch app.
- Create new untitled document.
- Code is using setAutosavedContentsFileURL to set temp file location. I can see the file package is created there. (+autosavesInPlace returns YES, btw.)
- Click the title bar to bring up the NSDocumentTitlebarPopoverView.
- Instantly, just by bringing up that popover, the temp document is moved from the temp folder to somewhere I can't find (or removed altogether?).

When the click occurs moveToURL:completionHandler is **not** getting called. Ditto writeSafelyToURL. I can't find the untitled file in the folder displayed in the NSDocumentTitlebarPopoverView or in the Trash or anywhere else. I've set symbolic breakpoints on every method I can think of (removeItemAtURL, moveItemAtURL, ...) and set breakpoints within my NSDocument subclass to see if presentedItemDidMoveToURL is called (nope).

If I click the folder popup and choose a different folder -moveToURL is then called. I can set a breakpoint there and print autosavedContentsFileURL to see that it thinks it's still in the original location where it mysteriously vanished from. Continuing I see that writeSafelyToURL is called and the document is reconstructed in the new location.

Oddly, subsequent new, untitled projects created *during this launch session* remain in the specified temporary folder location even when you click the title bar. It's not until you give it a name that the file is moved, and -moveToURL is correctly called. This is what I need to happen for the first untitled project, as well.

Once you relaunch the app the very first untitled document will exhibit the  problem with the vanishing temp file.

Other notes: -isEntireFileLoaded returns NO. This also happens on El Capitan. My app is not sandboxed. The untitled temp folder is in ~/Library/Application Support/MyApp. Tracing with fs_usage didn't offer any clues either.

Anything else I should explore? I'd sincerely appreciate any other ideas...

Update: another key point is I'm overriding writeSafelyToURL to write my package info. Using the normal writeSafelyToURL would direct writeToURL to write to a tmp location first then, once completed, move that to the true file URL. In my case I want to write in place because my package could be hundreds of megabytes in size so I'm only writing the changed internal data files.

Comment: When do you set `autosavedContentsFileURL`?

Comment: In my NSDocument subclass for initWithType.